# Backup SQLite database and restore it back when the Android application is installed

Tags: android, sqlite

I am building an Android application that fetches data from a cloud database and stores it in SQLite locally so that user does not need to fetch it again and again.

Now I need to find an efficient way to predefine a few rows in the SQLite database and provide it along with the APK. Is this possible? if so, how do I achieve it?

Comment: Create your SQLite file, fill it with data and then you can add it to your APK as *Asset*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You follow these steps :-

1. You create the database externally, populating it, and copy the file to your App's **assets** folder.

   - You may have to create the folder.
   - If using [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) then you will need to create a **databases** folder in the **assets** folder.
   - There are various tools for Creating and Managing SQLite Databases. e.g. *Db Browser for SQLite*.
2. You then need to modify your App to copy the file from the assets folder (or **assets/databases** folder) and then open the database. Noting that you only do the copy if the database doesn't already exist.

   - Using the [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) simplifies this process.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my time! If you don't mind can i know how upgrading the database work? Like, if i add few extra rows and update the values of previous rows in future updates?  Do i need to change the version?

Comment: You don't need to change the version (you'd need an alternative method of detecting changes though). However, increasing the version is probably the simplest. Increasing the version will result in the Database Helper's `onUpgrade` method running where you would either insert the new rows or perhaps re-copy the database (i.e. the DB shipped with the new version, this being needed for new installs).